# Parallel-Sequential "for" loop to set bits from bitarray to another bitarray is there any other faster way than this?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a bitarray1 which is 300000 bits in length and filled with boolean values (true & false). And I have a another bitarray2 of the same size(empty). I need to set bits for bitarray2 if certain conditions are matched in bitarray1. But need to do it sequentially. So, what will be the best way to perform it. I'm focused on speed. So, is it possible to perform this via PLINQ or any other parallel threading? I know parallel and sequence is two opposite things, but there should be an alternative way to do this :) as current method shown below is so slow.

Please see this simple illustration to understand what I really needed, I'm really bad at drawing things, so please bear with me :) [link](http://i57.tinypic.com/2ry6fjt.jpg)

```
Dim BitPosition1 As Int64 = 0
    Dim counter As Int64 = 0
    For CopyBits As Integer = 0 To Bitarray1.Length

        If CopyBits = bitarray1.length - 1 Then
            Exit For
        End If

        'if first four bits of "bitarray1" are "0100", then write "01" to "bitarray2" 
        If Bitarray1(BitPosition1) = False AndAlso Bitarray1(BitPosition1 + 1) = True AndAlso Bitarray1(BitPosition1 + 2) = False AndAlso Bitarray1(BitPosition1+3) = False Then

            Bitarray2.Set(counter, False)
            Bitarray2.Set(counter + 1, True)
            counter += 2
        End If

        'if first four bits of "bitarray1" are "1110", then write "10" to "bitarray2" 
        If Bitarray1(BitPosition1) = True AndAlso Bitarray1(BitPosition1 + 1) = True AndAlso Bitarray1(BitPosition1 + 2) = True AndAlso Bitarray1(BitPosition1+3) = False Then

            Bitarray2.Set(counter, True)
            Bitarray2.Set(counter + 1, False)
            counter += 2
        End If

        BitPosition1 += 4
```

Comment: Something is off with your code. If it does not match any of the two pattern, the algorithm stalls because the counter BitPosition1 is not incremented. The `for`- counter is not used but for a rather pointless check to exit the loop, that is only there because you iterate the loop one step too far. But it is not used for fetching the bits. Also your second array is at best half the size of the first one. Please check your code!

Comment: Your first If statement could be removed if you change your for loop to go to bitarray1.length-1 instead. You're not even checking BitPosition1+3. Why do you need it faster? Do you have a bunch of Bitarray1 ? If yes, just run each of them in parallel (1 thread per core).

Comment: @Nitram: Edited and corrected the sample, just ignore the mistakes :). That is a sample code ;). I just need to write to `bitarray2` if some pattern found in the `bitarray1`, but the thing is, I need to get the final `bitarray2` in orderly manner (eg: if a pattern found at end of the `bitarray1`, it should not write to the beginning of the `bitarray2` etc. ie. should be `sequential` :) )

Comment: @the_lotus: Corrections done :) . It needs to be faster because the actual code has many conditions and more complex than this code, this is just a sample ;), it contains around 8000000000 of bits (around 1GB of data, but it can vary), and it takes about 20 minutes to complete the loop :)

Comment: You should be using [AndAlso](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz.aspx) rather than And.

Comment: Thanks AndrewMorton :), made the corrections, it shortcircuit the conditions, so, it will be faster right ..

Comment: Also, if the BitArray is initially all zeros (false), then you do not need the `Bitarray2.Set(counter, False)` etc operations.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you can't do any full automatic parallel stuff because the positions in your first array do not map exactly to your second array and you need to keep things in order.

And while I doubt that things will get a lot faster when doing it parallel (never underestimate the overhead introduced by creating threads), you could use partitioning and multiple arrays that are merged at the end.

So what you basically need is a single isolated function that processes a specified part of your array.

For the offset and size values in your function I always use the sizes divided by 4, since you process your primary array in chucks of 4 elements.

So you end up with a function like this:

```
Function Process(source As Boolean(), offset As Integer, count As Integer, storage As Byte()) As Integer
  Dim current = offset
  Dim valuesInStorage = 0
  While current < offset + count
    If <YourLogic> Then
      storage(valuesInStorage * 2) = True/False   
      storage((valuesInStorage * 2) + 1) = True/False  
      valuesInStorage += 1
    End If
  End While
  Return valuesInStorage
End Function
```

Now you could call this function and have it process your entire array like this:

```
counter = Process(Bitarray1, 0, Bitarray1.Length \ 4, Bitarray2)
```

The `counter` variable would give the amount of samples (consisting of two boolean values) that was written into the target array. For it to contain the same value like in your sample, you have to multiply it by two.

Now this doesn't change much (other then the fact that it looks nicer ;-)) in matters of your code. But you can use this function to split of the amount of work in chucks.

Let's say you want to distribute your work across 4 threads:

```
Dim chucks = 4
Dim totalChucks = Bitarray1.Length \ chucks 
Dim chuckSize = CInt(Math.Ceil(totalChucks / chucks))
Dim storageList As New List(Of Boolean())
Dim taskList As New List(Of Task(Of Boolean))
For i = 0 To chucks - 1
  Dim bitArray(0 To (chuckSize * 2) - 1) As Boolean
  storageList.Add(bitArray)
  Dim offset = chuckSize * i
  taskList.Add(Task.Run(Function() Process(Bitarray1, offset, Math.Max(chuckSize, totalChucks - offset), bitArray)
End For

Dim results = Await Task.WhenAll(taskList)
Dim counter = 0
For i = 0 To chucks - 1
  Dim bitArray = storageList.Item(i)
  Dim count = results.Item(i)
  Array.ConstraintCopy(bitArray, 0, Bitarray2, counter * 2, count * 2)
End For
```

So what is basically done is that we define 4 chucks in your input array. Each one is fetched and stored in a separate array. After the parallel work on all 4 is done, the arrays are copied into the target array. `Array.ConstraintCopy` works extremely fast by working very low level. It is a lot faster then to copy each element by hand.

Further improvements could be to store the temporary storage arrays and use the same ones every time the code runs.

I think this is the only chance you have to get any improvement out of the parallel processing. Still I doubt that it will make much difference because the individual work is too little (according to your example) to really level the additional overhead you generate with this code.

Still I hope that helps.

Edit: Depending on what you need to do at the end with your data it may be not required to copy your data into one large array. If you for example need to write the data to the hard drive again you could easily write the 4 arrays in order. You got the counter for each array, telling you how many valid entries are in there.

Edit2: I just noticed that there actually is a `BitArray` class. :D You would need to change some of the types and constructors here and there, but it should be easily possible to change the code to use this class.

Edit3: Actually it is not that easy with the `BitArray` class. Because this class is very limited regarding the posibilities to transfer data to other arrays. It might be a good way to improve things if you avoid those class and use a byte array or what ever your actual source is and do the checks with some `and` statements.

Edit4: Some basic information regarding what bits and bytes are and how to match them. Lets use 2 Bytes (so 16 bits) as example. The following bit sequence (the start of the one from your example):

```
1010 0100 0000 1110
```

So those are two bytes.

1. Byte: `&HA4` = 164
2. Byte: `&H0E` = 14

In your example you got two patterns you want to find. `0100` and `1110`. Written as hexadecimal value this would be `&H04` and `&H0E`.

So now I give you a small example function that does the pattern matching.

```
Sub CheckPattern(source as Byte, upper As Boolean, storage As Byte(), ByRef storageCursor As Integer)
  'First fetch the upper or the lower 4 bytes and normalize them to the lower bytes of the field.
  Dim relevantData = If(upper, source >> 4, source And &HF)
  Dim dataToAdd As Byte = 0
  'Now the pattern matching
  If (relevantData And &H4) = &H4 Then
    dataToAdd = 1 '0 1
  ElseIf (relevantData And &HA) = &HA Then
    dataToAdd = 2 '1 0
  End If

  If dataToAdd <> 0 Then 
    Dim storageByte = storageCursor \ 4
    Dim storageBitOffset = (storageCursor Mod 4) * 2

    storage(storageByte) = storage(storageByte) And (dataToAdd << storageBitOffset)
    storageCursor += 1
  End If
End Sub
```

Now If you got your `byte` array containing those two bytes mentioned before you can call this function like so:

```
Dim resultArray(100) As Byte
Dim cursor As Integer = 0
Dim sourceByte() As Byte = {CByte(164), CByte(14)}
For i = 0 To sourceByte.Length - 1
  CheckPattern(sourceByte(i), False, resultArray, cursor)
  CheckPattern(sourceByte(i), True, resultArray, cursor)
End For
```

This will give you a single valid byte in your resulting sequence. This byte will hold 4 set bits that are set to the sequence you expect. The resulting byte has the decimal value 9.

What this checking function does step by step on bit-level:

`source` is `1010 0100`. `upper` is `False`. This means the `And` operation is performed to cut off the upper bytes. And on bit level simply matches all bits and the bits that are 1 in both values are 1 in the result. So:

```
      1010 0100
      And
&HF = 0000 1111
      =
      0000 0100
```

The matching of your patterns work the same way. If the `and` operation yields the same value as the one matched, the pattern is in the value.

For the upper value (so if  `upper` is `True`) a left shift operation by 4 bits is performed. This simply moves all bits 4 fields to the left. This turns `1010 0100` to `0000 1010`.

What may look a little confusing is the handling of the storage and the cursor.
You are always storing 1 bits for each matched patterns. So you can store 4 values in each byte. So we can "imagin" that you got 4 slots in each byte. What you need to know is where to store the value in your result storage. So you need the byte to store it and the slot inside the byte where to store it.

The math is simple. The integer division (note the `\` instead of the `/`) always returns the rounded down value and the modulo operation will give you the slot inside the byte. Now you just need your value shifted right to the correct slot and use a bitwise-or to add it to the byte.

Comment: Many thanks :), I'll go through your code. Meanwhile, Please see this simple illustration to understand what I really needed, I'm bad at drawing things, so please bear with me :) [link](http://i57.tinypic.com/2ry6fjt.jpg)

Comment: That much is clear. I just wonder how you get such a big source array in the first place and what you want to do with the data. If you read it from the harddrive or the network and need to write it there again, it may be easier and faster to stream the data instead of buffering the entire data set.

Comment: Yes, it involves read the file and write again. Currently, the file is read from the hardrive, via the `File.ReadAllBytes` method, still it doesn't connect to any file server or anything else. At the moment, my actual code reads the whole file at once I'm hoping to improve it by setting it to read small portion by portion of the file and write it back again. :)

Comment: I think that is more of the issue than anything else. You could read the file into a smaller buffer, analyze the small chunk and push it out again. Also I suggest you match the upper and lower 4 bit of each byte using bitwise operations using `and` instead of using a bit array. I do not think that you need anything paralell in this case, because reading and writing to the hard drive will be the slowest part of the entire thing by far.

Comment: Further, For Edit2&3: Yes there actually is a `BitArray` :) apparently you have written the code by using just `Array`. I used `BitArray` over `ByteArray` is because, `byte array` doesn't hold any `bits`, So, needed to use `bitarray`. Furthermore, if I copy again those bits from `bitarray` to a `Array` it will consume many times of RAM than a `BitArray` to hold the same data set :(

Comment: A byte array does hold bits :D 8 Bits are one byte ;-) That is the reason why I suggested you look into handling your data directly as a byte array and match your pattern with some and operations.

Comment: `because reading and writing to the hard drive will be the slowest part of the entire thing by far`.. Actually, it will not just write the data back, as you can see it doesn't find any matching patterns in every iteration, so, the `bitarray2` will be less in file size, further the collected data won't just written back to the hard-drive, it has further things to do with the collected data in bitarray2, so, final output will be different and it won't take much time to write to the hard-drive. My only issue is the finding the pattern as fast as possible :)

Comment: Yet. But if you match the pattern while you are reading the file, the time required to actually do the pattern matching will be much much lower than the time required to read the data. Still I think matching the data in a `byte` array with a byte pattern will be faster than what you are doing right now.

Comment: As I'm trying to find a pattern of 4bits at one time, it will take much time to convert 1byte to 8 bits in each iteration and find the pattern, isn't it. so, the code won't be very efficient, will it? If I do it, I'll have to surf through the internet to find another code which will covert 1 byte to 8 bits etc. :)

And, sometimes, it requires to find another pattern in the Bitarray2 as well, and the resulting bitarray might be checked for other patterns as well..  so, matching patterns while I read the file won't make much difference. :)

Comment: Give me a moment. I am editing the answer to give you a example how to match your pattern on byte base.

Comment: @Nitram I think you meant to write [Array.ConstrainedCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.constrainedcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rather than Array.ConstraintCopy.